# postgresql-setup --upgrade failure trying to upgrade databases from postgresql 14 to postgresql 15 on Fedora 38

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgresql-15

Trying to update postgresql using the postgresql-setup package I get the following log file:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for system-defined composite types in user tables  ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                 ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Creating dump of global objects                             ok
Creating dump of database schemas                           
*failure*

Consult the last few lines of "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20230629T143346.173/log/pg_upgrade_dump_136813.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.
Failure, exiting
```

But the file listed does not exist and neither does the pg_upgrade_output.d directory.

Running the command as root yields the same result.